# How to enable remember password in case of AJAX login?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web, authentication

I have a web app where I have a simple login box. There is no form to submit and the login procedure is implemented via jQuery AJAX.

In such a scenario, how can I make the web browser display the "Do you want the browser to remember the password?" dialog?

Thanks in advance!

**NOTE:** I'm looking for a solution that works at least in the most recent version of all major browsers.

**EDIT:** I do use cookies for remembering user login. The problem is that browsers don't offer to remember the password.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="window loginWindow sn-login">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="UserName" placeholder='Username' />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="Password" placeholder='Password' />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="RememberMe" />
            <label for="RememberMe">Remember my login</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="loginSubmit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var $userName = $("#UserName"),
    $rememberMe = $("#RememberMe"),
    $password = $("#Password");

var name = $userName.val(), pw = $password.val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/UserActions/LogIn",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { password: pw, email: name },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            if ($rememberMe.is(":checked")) {
                // Omitted for brevity
            }

            window.location.reload();
        }
        else {
            // Omitted for brevity
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by - no form to submit?

Comment: use cookies as said in the comment above, or localstorage with polyfill for older browsers

Comment: Yes, I use cookies. That wasn't the question.

Comment: @Yoda - there is no `form` element on the page

Comment: @Venemo just create your own dialog box using fancybox, colorbox, jqueryui and ask with the question with yes or not answer and then act accordingly.

Comment: @Venemo suggested this because to use the browser's save password feature you need a form tag which has to post the data with password type field in it.

Comment: @Yoda - If I create a custom dialog, the browser still won't save the password...

Comment: Added HTML+JS to the question

Comment: @Venemo ok I thought you want to save in the cookie and not in the browser's keychain! Just create a form element as a wrapper for your controls and use the form's submit handler to perform a ajax call as you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a form element as a wrapper for your controls and use the form's submit handler to perform a ajax call as you are doing.

```
<form id="myform">
<div class="window loginWindow sn-login">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="UserName" placeholder='Username' />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="Password" placeholder='Password' />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="RememberMe" />
            <label for="RememberMe">Remember my login</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="loginSubmit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Change your script like this:

```
$('.loginSubmit').on('click', function(){

$("#myform").submit(function(){


var $userName = $("#UserName"),
    $rememberMe = $("#RememberMe"),
    $password = $("#Password");

var name = $userName.val(), pw = $password.val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/UserActions/LogIn",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { password: pw, email: name },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            if ($rememberMe.is(":checked")) {
                // Omitted for brevity
            }

            window.location.reload();
        }
        else {
            // Omitted for brevity
        }
    }
});
return false;
});

});
```

Comment: there might be some braces issue as i have written the code here itself not in any IDE.

Comment: Did not have the chance to try yet, will report back when I do

Comment: @pstanton it worked for me back in 2013 as these were the supported browsers for the project.

Comment: @SiddharthPandey no problem, just adding info

Answer (score 0):

Use a form to trigger the browser's built-in "remember password" option, but set a `submit` event on it that cancels the default event and handles your AJAX login instead.

Comment: "to trigger" - how exactly? Nowadays browsers are tricky, they don't show the remember password box just because you submit the form and then cancel it.

Comment: I'm fairly sure they do, so long as you properly listen to the `submit` event and handle it appropriately...